# Why is the written python file 5120 bytes in size?

Tags: python

I wrote a python script with python3.4 and ran it on my chromebook with Tegra K1 processor.

Here is the code

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 1, 1
    for i in range(n - 1):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a

i = 2
while True:
    n = fib(i)
    with open('nums', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(n))
print(n)
i += 1
```

It was running for few minutes, and then I shut it down by Ctrl+C. After that, I checked the content of the written file called `nums`. but found out that only `1` was written into it but the file size was `5120 bytes`.

Why was the file size 5120 bytes?

Comment: You keep opening the file in "w" mode, overwriting the current data. Did you want "a" mode to append new data? Better still... how about opening it once before the loop?

Comment: also note, the code posted has an indentation error in the with clause.

Comment: To add to this, you may not be closing the file-handle properly as well.  Use `with` to open files with python so the handle gets closed regardless of errors etc.

Comment: Is the indentation correct in the question text? I'd imagine you want the `i += 1` line to be inside the loop (or there's not much point to either the loop or the increment statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop logic seems incorrect: You are opening the file each time when you have merely one number to write. Here's the fixed version:

```
with open('nums', 'w') as f:
    i = 2
    while True:
        n = fib(i)
        f.write(str(n))
        i += 1
```

Also, as you are halting the script by `Ctrl+C`, you may want to add another line of `f.flush()` after `f.write`, to make sure the change is flushed onto the disk.

**EDITED:**

Alternatively, as @tdelaney has mentioned in the comment (thank you @tdelaney :) ), you could use the append mode by simply replacing `with open('nums', 'w')` with `with open('nums', 'wa')`. However this approach:

1. Is of low efficiency: The file needs to be opened and closed once for each number while it's really unnecessary.
2. Does not handle the file well: Content of the file would not be cleared when the script starts. Thus when you invoke the script for multiple times, the file would contain results from previous runs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought that was an operation system behavior, but it was a bug in program. 

But why 'nums' size is 5120? It was just a coincidence?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the work inside the write loop

```
def fib()

with open("nums", "a") as f:

  <bulk of code>

  f.write(str(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your file is big is because it keeps looping forever without stopping so when you terminate the program there are a lot of `0` bytes written there.

Here is a working solution with

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 1, 1
    for i in range(n - 1):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a


with open('nums', 'w') as f:
    i = 1
    while i <= 10:
        n = fib(i)
        f.write(str(n) + "\n")
        i += 1
```